# Strict filtering with Jinja operator 'in'

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I want to do a strict filtering like the below:

> {{ dog in 'dogga, cat' }} returns *false*

Is there a way obtain this strict filtering or correct me if i'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 4):

What is your Jinja version? Both of the following constructs work fine for me:

```
{{ 1 in [1, 2, 3] }} == True
{{ 1 in [18, 2, 3] }} == False
```

**[Edit]:**

You're comparing the variable `dog` with a string here:

```
{{ dog in 'dogga, cat' }}
```

I assume you want to compare string `'dog'` with list of items, so then you need to convert your string into list first (it makes sense to do it in the Python, not in template) and the do the comparison:

```
{{ 'dog' in ['dogga', 'cat'] }} == False
```

Or do if you really want to do it in template:

```
{{ 'dog' in 'dogga, cat'.split()|map('trim') }} returns False
{{ 'dog' in 'dogga, cat, dog '.split()|map('trim') }} returns True
```

Comment: @user3240361 Jinja2 has versions too. Latest is currently 2.7.3.

Comment: i got it. I was doing it wrong

Comment: I have edited my question. Is there a way to do it.

Comment: @user3240361 Ok, I found two issues with your current approach.